# Create object from array containing another array

Tags: javascript

I need your little help to create the obj object you see on the code below.

```js
// let arr1 = ['Monday', ['Pasta', 'Watermelon', 'Milk']],
// let arr2 = ['Tuesday', ['Cookies', 'Chips', 'Peach']]

const obj = {
  "Monday": ['Pasta', 'Watermelon', 'Milk'],
  "Tuesday": ['Cookies', 'Chips', 'Peach']
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key} -> ${value}`);
}
```

Given **arr1** and **arr2** I have to create the ***obj*** object shown.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `obj[arr1[0]] = arr1[1]`. And the same for `arr2`.

Comment: `Object.fromEntries([arr1, arr2])`

Comment: For reference: Barmar's comment is using [computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript) for the keys; you can create a key from each array's first element, and then assign it the second array as its value.

Comment: @James not necessary. fromEntries needs an array of key-value pair arrays. Each of the source arrays is a single key-value pair array.